# Does there exists any non-trivial group homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

If $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ then it should be of the form $f(q)=qf(1)$, then how it will work for irrationals?

Comment: [Relevant:  Baire property implies that group homomorphisms are continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591521/group-homomorphism-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbq-without-axiom-of-choice)

Comment: as a group, $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space, so any projection will work.

Comment: It clearly depends on the group-operation.

Comment: operation is addition..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the axioms of set theory. Using the axiom of choice, $\mathbb{R}$ has a basis as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, so you can write down examples of nontrivial linear maps $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}$ by defining then arbitrarily on such a basis.

On the other hand, it's consistent with the negation of the axiom of choice that every homomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is continuous, which means it is necessarily zero since its image must be connected. See [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49388/is-the-non-triviality-of-the-algebraic-dual-of-an-infinite-dimensional-vector-sp) for some details.