# Let $r$ be a irrational. Is there a homomorphism $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f(r) = 0$, $f \ne 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

Let $r$ be an irrational number. I want to find a homomorphism  $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. a map such that $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, which satisfies $f(r) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.

I think I can accomplish this by finding a homomorphism $\phi \colon \mathbb{R}/(r\mathbb{Q}) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(1+r\mathbb{Q}) = 1$, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: What kind of homomorphism? $\mathbb R$ has many structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider $\mathbb R$ as  a vector space over $\mathbb Q$.  $ \{1, r\}$ is linearly independent and it can be extended to a basis for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$. You can assign arbitrary values to $f$ on a basis and extend it linearly to the whole space.

[Axiom of Choice is assumed].

Comment: And the axiom of choice cannot be avoided: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591521